# Is it possible to know the last update date of an App?

Tags: store, windows-10-mobile, app-update

On the Windows Phone 8.1 Store each App page showed at the bottom of the page the last date of update of the App.

I found that information useful, in order to understand if an App was actively developed or abandoned on the Store.

I can't find the same information for the Apps on the Windows 10 Mobile Store, nor on the Windows Store on the web.

Is it still possible to read the last update date of an App?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Windows store does not support this feature in Windows 10.

It is one of the top requested feature by the users. I suggest you to give feedback through the built-in feedback app.

As a work around for now you can assume that almost all apps that have the "built for windows 10" mark in the store are actively developed. Though it cannot mean constant updates for apps, it is the only way to see whether an app is recently updated or not.

This is one of the essential features that windows 10 is still lacking.